# Empty table before insert pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a script for importing data from rss files, and I want to empty my table before insert, so I don't have any old entries in my database, but I can't get the syntax right, because nothing gets deleted.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM $table");

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(id,name) VALUES(:id,:name)ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=:name");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':name' => $name));

    $db->commit();
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    //Something went wrong rollback!
    $db->rollBack();
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

## EDIT

I have tried with Truncate, but thought I needed delete since truncate does not empty/delete anything:

```
try {
    $db->beginTransaction();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("TRUNCATE TABLE $table");

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(id,name) VALUES(:id,:name)ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=:name");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':name' => $name));

    $db->commit();
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    //Something went wrong rollback!
    $db->rollBack();
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Most likely you have `safe_update`s enabled, which means you can't execute a `DELETE`/`UPDATE` without a condition. What you probably want is a `TRUNCATE`, but if you really want a `DELETE`, you might consider adding: `WHERE id > 0` (since that will match all rows most likely)

Comment: With the answers below, just be sure you are aware that `DELETE` will keep your `auto_increment` at it's current number, and `TRUNCATE` will reset it.  Not to say it's an issue in your case, just some info you might find useful.

Comment: @Zak He's binding the ID in his query. Doesn't appear to be using an `auto_increment`. Of course, who knows - since there's no schema definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `` TRUNCATE TABLE `tableName` ``, not `DELETE FROM tableName`.

Here's the **[Manual page on the subject.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html)**

Comment: `DELETE FROM tableName` is perfectly valid syntax as well. This is most likely safe_updates at play.

Comment: @Zak No, it's valid syntax regardless. It is correct that `DELETE` won't reset `auto_increment`, but that doesn't mean the syntax is invalid.

Comment: @Colin -- Yes, hence my vote up on your comment ;-)  My bad on the semi-improper semantics

Comment: See my edit. There has to be some setting Im missing, since Truncate does not empty the table.

Comment: @Garreth00 You're never actually _executing_ the statement. You're just preparing it.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Ah, okay. How do I execute it?

Comment: @Garreth00 The same way you execute your other statement _right_ below it. `$stmt->execute()`

Comment: @ColinMorelli I did not think execute could be empty. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same thing today and after extensive testing have found that `TRUNCATE` cannot actually be rolled back so you may want to consider this.

An easy test is if you add a new record to your table then run your script. The record should be removed, however in my instance it was still there.

Here is an example snippet from my code:

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

try {

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM trade_customer");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE trade_customer SELECT * FROM cp_imp_customer");
        $stmt->execute();

}

catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
    echo "FAILED - " . $Exception->getMessage( ) . "(" . (int)$Exception->getCode( ) . ") - " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
    echo "Transaction ended, no changes were made to the live table" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
    die;
}

// commit on success
$dbh->commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

`TRUNCATE TABLE $table` will empty the table and reset the autonumbering.